# Using LaTeX/MathJax in the comments on Blogger

Tags: latex, blogger, mathjax

I recently made my blog on Blogger compatible with LaTeX using one of the many solutions you can find by just searching how to do this on google. However, this solution doesn't apply to the comments to posts on Blogger. 
The solution I am using is the one given by the first answer in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13865/how-to-use-latex-on-blogspot

Is there a way of getting the comments on Blogger to render/compile LaTeX/MathJax?

I am currently using google+ comments on my blog and I am having trouble setting up a different commenting format to try and get LaTeX to work with the comments.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  Also, it would be helpful to provide the link to the solution you did use and explain why it doesn't apply in more detail.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't apply. I mean I can vaguely gather that because I have google+ comments enabled it might be affecting the embedded comments from reading LaTeX. The only code I've used is what is given in the link I attached. Sorry I can't give more info. I am not much of a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Google+ comments are inserted via an iframe, see http://googlesystem.blogspot.de/2013/04/blogger-comments-powered-by-google.html?m=1

This means you will not be able to inject JavaScript from the surrounding page. In particular, you cannot get MathJax support in the comments.